# Is there a way of creating a hero image with text on top of it without using background-image: url();?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way of creating a hero image with text on top of it without using `background-image: url();` and `position relative`?

Maybe it can be done with css grid, not sure? I got this far:

https://codepen.io/labanino/pen/NejZEy?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without `position:relative` and `background:url()`

```css
url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Solid");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.hero {
  img {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <h1>This is my dummy text!</h1>
  <img src="//unsplash.it/600/200" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why? Pos relative is the best way here

U can use height 0 and overflow visible on text

Answer (score 0):

This accomplishes what you're asking for:

```
<div class="hero">
    <h1 class="theText">This is my dummy text!</h1>
    <img class="theImage" src="//unsplash.it/600/200" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Solid');

* { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
body { 
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #2F4858;
}

.hero {
    position: relative;
}

.theImage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.theText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    width: 100vw;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: calc(-50vw);
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```